# Building mySQL Query with PHP params -- "first AND"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build an sql query with php where each GET variable (if set) gets appended to the query.  So for example:

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deleted = 0 AND ({$dueQ} {$paidQ} {$completedQ} {etc. etc. etc.}) ";
```

Where each parameter is created like so:

```
$due = $_GET['due'];
if (isset($due)) {
    $dueQ = " AND due = '0'";
}
```

So I'm checking to see if each get parameter is set, then if it is, adding that string to the query.

My question is this...
How do I create the query such that the first parameter doesn't start with "AND"?  Since I don't know which will be the first parameter to be appended to the query, I can't find a way to account for it not starting with "AND". Right now the query reads "**AND** due='0' AND...".  Make sense?

Comment: If it's all `AND` conditions, there is no need for parenthesis and you can add it directly after `deleted = 0`. And if you plan to use the sent-in values, you should use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Didn't want to complicate things with my question but there's also and and/or parameter, so they could be either and or or within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your parameters to an array, then `implode()` them with `AND` as the glue:

```
$params = array();
if (isset($_GET['due']))
    $params[] = "due = '0'";

if (isset($_GET['paid']))
    $params[] = "paid = '0'";

...etc...

$dbQuery = "SELECT ... WHERE deleted = 0 AND ".implode(' AND ', $params);
//SELECT ... WHERE deleted = 0 AND due = '0' AND paid = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable to check whether a condition has already been met or not, and based on the status of boolean variable, incrementally construct the query, like this:

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deleted = 0";

$flag = false;

$due = $_GET['due'];
if(isset($dueQ)){
    $dbQuery .= " AND due = '0'"; 
    $flag = true;
}

if(isset($paidQ)){
    if($flag){
        $dbQuery .= " something = 'something'";
    }else{
        $dbQuery .= " AND somethingElse = 'somethingElse'";
        $flag = true;
    } 
}

if(isset($completedQ)){
    if($flag){
        $dbQuery .= " something = 'something'";
    }else{
        $dbQuery .= " AND somethingElse = 'somethingElse'";
        $flag = true;
    } 
}

// etc.
```